# how to export and save all data from my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension, And its working very smoothly. All data saved to `AppData->Local->pjkbkijbifbaboihoamgmbklokdohlpd(extension id)->000003.log` .I wish to export all data from browser directly. So don't have to go to folder and copy log file.Is there possible to export `000003.log` file directly?

Comment: If by "directly" you mean from outside of Chrome then there are several LevelDB export tools, but it may take some time to find/build the correct one. The usual and practical approach is to export the data from within the extension in a JSON file (there could be existing answers for that or you can inspect [other extensions](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/blob/master/manage/import-export.js#L296)).

Comment: I just want log file from browser

Comment: You seem to repeat what you already wrote in the question but it's still unclear what exactly you want and what's wrong with the suggestions in my comment above. The thing is, there's no magic trick to export that file as is from an extension. You can write a utility that copies this file and invoke it using nativeMessaging but that seems even more complicated than what I already suggested.